# SQL Script Invalid Column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @tblRCatOmitTemp TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
RCatId          int     NOT NULL,
CountryId   int     NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @tblRCatOmitTemp
    SELECT  RCatId, CountryId 
    FROM    dbo.tblRCatOmit TABLOCKX

DROP TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit(   
            ID     INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        RCatId     INT NOT NULL,
        CountryId  INT NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit  
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RCatOmit PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID);  

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit   
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RCatOmit_rcatId FOREIGN KEY (RCatId)     
    REFERENCES dbo.tblRCat (RCatID);   

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RCatOmit_countryId FOREIGN KEY (CountryId)     
    REFERENCES dbo.tblCountry (CountryID)        

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblRCatOmit ON
INSERT INTO 
    dbo.tblRCatOmit(
        ID,
        RCatID,
        CountryID)
SELECT
    ID,
    RCatID,
    CountryID
FROM 
    @tblRCatOmitTemp
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblRCatOmit OFF

COMMIT TRANSACTION tblRCatOmit;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'Something Happend!'
    ROLLBACK;
END CATCH
```

I have to add a new IDENTITY field as well as PKs and FKs's to a table.  I'm trying to save the data into a temp table, drop the original table and then recreate it.

When I run this script I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'ID'

I'm guessing it is doing a pre-compile and letting me know that ID doesn't exist in the current table.

What do I need to do to modify this script so it runs?

When I double click the `Invalid column name 'ID'` message it brings me to this part of the script:

```
INSERT INTO 
    dbo.tblRCatOmit(ID,
            RCatID,
            CountryID)
```

Comment: Why are you turning identity insert on and then not supplying a value? I would recommend a better name than ID for your column. Maybe something like RCatOmitID. I would also suggest removing the tbl prefeix on your tables. They do nothing except add extra keystrokes and make it harder to see what table you are referencing.

Comment: @SeanLange - Agreed!  Dealing with legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblRCatOmitTemp') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tblRCatOmitTemp
    END

CREATE TABLE #tblRCatOmitTemp (
    RCatId int NOT NULL,
    CountryId int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tblRCatOmitTemp
    SELECT  RCatId, CountryId 
    FROM    dbo.tblRCatOmit TABLOCKX

DROP TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit(   
            ID     INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        RCatId     INT NOT NULL,
        CountryId  INT NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit  
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RCatOmit PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID);  

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit   
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RCatOmit_rcatId FOREIGN KEY (RCatId)     
    REFERENCES dbo.tblRCat (RCatID);   

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RCatOmit_countryId FOREIGN KEY (CountryId)     
    REFERENCES dbo.tblCountry (CountryID)        

INSERT INTO 
    dbo.tblRCatOmit(
        RCatID,
        CountryID)
SELECT
    RCatID,
    CountryID
FROM 
    #tblRCatOmitTemp

COMMIT TRANSACTION tblRCatOmit;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'Something Happend!'
    ROLLBACK;
END CATCH
```

- If you have any amount of data at all use a Temp Table not a table variable, because performance will be a lot better!
- Next don't build the ID on the temp table it is arbitrary if you do that and on your insert back to your newly recreated table it will build it there for you.  Also means no need to set identity insert on.

If you don't want to use a temp table and add that insert you could also use sp_rename to rename your existing table....

And if you don't care about ordinal position of the columns then simply add the column and then the keys.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit  
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RCatOmit PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID);  

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit   
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RCatOmit_rcatId FOREIGN KEY (RCatId)     
    REFERENCES dbo.tblRCat (RCatID);   

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblRCatOmit    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RCatOmit_countryId FOREIGN KEY (CountryId)     
    REFERENCES dbo.tblCountry (CountryID)
```